# How to get a character delimited substring in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, websphere, zos

I have a column "employee_Id" in my Table "Employee".

employee_Id is having employee name and date of birth. For example :

`Jason-21996` and `Buttler`

Please help me  write a select query which returns `Jason` and `Buttler` as output.

This is the query I am trying :

`select substring(employee_Id,1, LOCATE('-',employee_Id) - 1) as Emp_ID from Employee`

I am seeing this error:

```
SQL Error [42815]: THE DATA TYPE, LENGTH, OR VALUE OF ARGUMENT 3 OF SUBSTRING IS INVALID. SQLCODE=-171, SQLSTATE=42815, DRIVER=4.9.78
```

Edit 1: As suggested by @Mark, I have edited the query as follows

`select substring(employee_Id,1, LOCATE('-',employee_Id || '-') - 1) as Emp_ID from Employee`

I am getting the same error. I tried to run the LOCATE and found that it is returning the index as 15 for Buttler as the column length is 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following as is.

```
select substring(employee_Id, 1, LOCATE('-', employee_Id || '-') - 1) as Emp_ID 
from 
(
          SELECT 'Jason-21996' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Buttler'     FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
) Employee (employee_Id);
```

Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If your version of DB2 supports regular expressions, then a simple method is `regexp_substr()`:

```
regexp_substr(employee_id, '^[^-]+')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=6d53064a31ce0811b030e18ee0bbcc5f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: SQL Error [42884]: NO AUTHORIZED REGEXP_SUBSTR NAMED  HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.9.78

Comment: @VarshaKumari What's the problem with your query?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein, I have updated the error in question, please have a look

Comment: Some `employee_id` may not have '-' character in its value. Try `substring(employee_Id, 1, LOCATE('-', employee_Id || '-') - 1)`.

Comment: Yes @MarkBarinstein , you are right ..some employee_id are not having '-' character, and  this query returns the location index as 15(the size of the column) for them.. Any way to handle this?

Comment: Does the query I suggested return error / wrong result?

Comment: @VarshaKumari . . . I've added a db<>fiddle.  This works in DB2.  This works with the data you have provided.

Comment: @GordonLinoff [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=functions-regexp-substr) may not exist even in DB2 12 for Z/OS. It must be at FL504 according to the link to have it enabled. The link you provided is for Db2 for LUW - it's different product with quite a similar set of SQL functions, but not at 100%.

Comment: Yes, @MarkBarinstein, it is showing the same error I have mentioned in my question